# how to restrict invalidate in input type datetime-local

Tags: html, angular, momentjs, datetime-format, angular-moment

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step="1">
```

In that, how to avoid invalid date input. Suppose I am insert date like **"11:11:1111"**
in "mm-dd-yyyy" format. how can solve this using Moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the isValid() method to make sure the DateTime is valid, or see my second example of checking if a date is older than a specified year.
Example:

```js
// Variables
var datetimeElement = document.getElementById("datetime");
var statusElement = document.getElementById("status");

// A simple function to check the validity of a date using the isValid() method
function checkValidity() {
  if (moment(datetimeElement.value.toString()).isValid()) {
    // Datetime is in a valid format
    statusElement.innerHTML = 'Valid datetime';
  } else {
    // Invalid datetime format
    statusElement.innerHTML = 'Invalid datetime';
  }
}

// Check date validity every 1 seconds and update the text
setInterval(function() {
    checkValidity();
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<input id="datetime" type="datetime-local" step="1">
<p id="status"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In the example above, if you try and enter a date such as 11/11/11111, it will say that it is invalid. If you want to prevent dates that are before a specified year, you can use the following:

```js
// Variables
var datetimeElement = document.getElementById("datetime");
var statusElement = document.getElementById("status");

// A simple function to check the validity of a date using the isValid() method
function checkValidity() {
  if (moment(datetimeElement.value.toString()).isValid()) {
    // Datetime is in a valid format    
    // Check if datetime is older than the specified year (1900)
    if (moment(datetimeElement.value.toString()).format('YYYY') < 1900) {
      // Invalid date
      statusElement.innerHTML = 'Invalid datetime';
    } else {
      // Datetime is valid
      statusElement.innerHTML = 'Valid datetime';
    }
  } else {
    // Datetime is invalid
    statusElement.innerHTML = 'Invalid datetime';
  }
}

// Check date validity every 1 seconds and update the text
setInterval(function() {
    checkValidity();
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<input id="datetime" type="datetime-local" step="1">
<p id="status"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you enter a year older than 1900, such as 01/01/1899, in the example code above, it will say it is invalid.

I hope this has helped your problem.